# How can I gather system information via scripting?

Tags: vbscript, output

My original question was to quickly and easily gather hardware information from a computer. I was also hoping to do this over a network, rather than sit down at each PC and run a script. Scriptomatic 2.0 was the solution to my problem.

One thing I would like to note about it: **It seems to work well only under Windows XP.** When I ran it on Windows 7, it did not function properly.

During my long night of trying to solve the problem myself, I came across this wonderful tool. It had a ton of sample scripts, all of which applied to my situation.

http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/misc/wmi/scr_1343.asp

This program is free by evaluation. The evaluation will never run out however, as stated by the program. Each time you compile, it takes a second longer. However, if you open a new window the counter resets. This program was extremely helpful for someone like me who knows basic programming, but nothing about VB scripting.

Comment: You substantially changed your question twice. Please don't do that. Also, please don't put meta information like "solved" in the subject of your question. Questions are considered solved when they have an accepted answer.

Comment: I don't see the problem. You can see my edit history to know what I originally asked. I've seen too often around here and on other sites that users get partial help that allows them to solve the problem themselves. They never specifically say what it was they did to solve the issue. It's really aggravating to Google only to not find the full solution. I've even Googled a similar problem that I had asked here before, and FOUND my own question.

So I'm heavily revising to help anyone else that may have had my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has provided a free tool called Scriptomatic 2.0 which automatically generates scripts in vbscript that allows you to get hardware and software information.  You can download the tool from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=12028

Comment: Looks like that tool only functions properly under XP. Currently playing around with it. It's doing exactly what I need so far.

Comment: Glad to know it was useful